# remove/restore elements, maintaining their events and element's children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came to a situation where I need to edit the following in a way that, on some event (lets assume the 'click' event in this case) I need to remove (or unwrap?) the `.container` and the `.header` and have the `.itemlist` still visible/available on the page. And then, I need to restore `.container` and `.header` back again on some other event, while still maintain the event listeners on the `a` tags, and if possible, without removing the said items from the DOM. Is this possible?

```
<ul class="container">
  <li class="header"><a href="#">delete</a> | <a href="#">edit</a></li>
    <ul class="itemlist">
       <li>some item</li>
       <li>some other item</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/iwiju3

this is just a proof of concept, not sure is what you want, but let me know!

```
$(function() {
    $("button").toggle(function() {
        $(".container").wrap('<span></span>'); //wrap all with span
        $(".itemlist").unwrap(); //unwrap container
        $(".header").hide(); //hide header
    },
    function() {
        $("span").wrap('<ul class="container"></ul>'); //rewrap with container
        $(".itemlist").unwrap(); //remove span
        $(".header").show(); //show header
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** if you need to create the `.header` again in a second time, there is no reason for remove it, just hide!
the `.container` can be unwrapped but since `.header` and `.itemlist` are two distinct elements you need to wrap it with something like `<span>` for wrap it again in a second time!